# What's the meaning of "Frantic pace"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I've just seen the phrase "frantic pace" in following sentence, could anyone explain what its mean?

> Go into any mall these days and you'll find many people shopping at a frantic pace,...

Answer (score 0):

"pace/rush/haste" have collocation with "frantic", i.e. "**frantic pace/rush/haste**".
"**pace**" means the speed at which sb/sth walks, runs or moves (According to Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary)
"**frantic**" means extremely hurried and using a lot of energy, but not very organized (According to Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English)
then, **frantic pace means moving hurriedly**

> The game started at a frantic pace.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but your example doesn't work. People move  at a frantic pace, but we don't say _there was a frantic pace_.